# Is the sentence "I think you have got a temperature" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm an English speaker living amongst people who speak English as a foreign language, this sometimes gets me very confused.

I found the following sentence in an English school book:

> "I think you have a temperature"

Is this by any chance right? Would surprise me if it were.

Comment: Yes, it's correct and idiomatic for "you have a fever".

Answer (score 4):

This is a little confusing, as you've used two different sentences. Let's examine them both.

> I think you have a temperature.

This is fine. "**temperature**" is commonly used in the UK to mean "**fever**", so I'd imagine the book was published by a British company. The sentence just means *"I have a fever."*

Next:

> I think you **have got** a temperature.

This means the same thing as the first one. The "**have got**" is not necessarily recognized universally as being grammatically correct, but it is widely used colloquially to mean the same as "**have**", as in:

> I've got three cars. => I **have got** three cars.

This is especially common in a lot of British speech.

Anyway, whichever of the two sentences you're talking about, both are okay. I would say the first sentence (without "**got**") is probably more commonly used.

I'd imagine neither would be entirely comfortable to an American ear, though. Can't speak to other regions of the world, but presumably there would be similar subtle differences.

Comment: 'Fever' from 'temperature' via 'elevated temperature'. This sort of unexpected sense occurs frequently in English. For example, 'speedy' means 'going at a high speed' not 'going at some unspecified speed'; 'have a date' usually means 'have an amorous meeting', though it _can_ mean 'have fixed a date for an appointment etc' or 'eat a date'.

Comment: As an American English speaker, I concur with your answer. _Fever_ and _temperature_ are interchangeable. "_I think you have a temperature._" is an acceptable way to communicate the message. "_...have got..._" also works, but isn't as pleasant.

Comment: Have a temperature is used all of the time in AmE.

Comment: @DavidM Okie dokie. I did not know that. I hope this was clear, but I didn't mean to imply that nobody in America would ever use it, just that in my experience with AmE speakers *fever* is a much more common term. However, given that you spell *colour* without a *u*, I'm willing to allow that you are probably more familiar with AmE than I am. Just out of interest, do you think there's a geographical/dialect thing going on? As in, does *temperature* sound more Southern/Eastern/Alaskan/etc? Or are they both totally equivalent to your ear?

Comment: Totally equivalent to my ear.

Comment: @DavidM Interesting! I shall add this to my memory banks for future reference and great justice.

Answer (score 0):

Pedantically it is wrong/right.

Everyone (and object for that matter) has a temperature.  That temperature may be 98.6F (~37 C) or it may be higher or lower than that.  Therefore saying *you have a temperature* is like saying that you exist on the physical plane.   In other words:  [Thank you Captain Obvious.](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gB8ewAdhY7Q)

The expression I think you *have (have got/are running/etc.)* a temperature means *have a fever*.  The usage is colloquial and readily understood.

My wife (the pediatrician) has a pet peeve about this one. But, it is entirely understandable to people when you say this rather obvious statement.